# Plotting a piecewise function in python with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

**Note: This is for homework so please don't post full code responses, just help on what I'm misusing would be appreciated**

I'm trying to plot a piecewise defined function where when 0 < x <= 10 it will be a constant (KQ/10) and for x > 10 it will be KQ/x for 10 < x < 50. Currently my result comes back as a single value instead of my expected result of an array with a constant value up until x > 10 and then varying values until x = 50

My current code

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy


x = np.linspace(0, 50, 1)
R = 10
r = np.linspace(10, 50, 1)
k = 1/(4*np.pi*constants.epsilon_0)
Q = 1
def inside(x):
    return k*Q/R
def outer(x):
    return k*Q/x
result = np.piecewise(
    x,
    [x <= R, x > R ],
    [lambda x: inside(x), lambda x: outer(x)]
)
result
#plt.plot(x,result)
#plt.axis([0, 50,0, 500000])
#plt.xlabel('x')
#plt.ylabel('y')```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x = np.linspace(0, 50, 1)`

isnt how linspace works... this only creates one data point ...

`x = np.linspace(0, 50, 10000)` ... would create 10k datapoints

perhaps you wanted `np.arange(0,50,1)` ?